# temporarily change $http.defaults.transformResponse

Tags: ajax, angularjs

How can I customize $http in angularjs such that it will accept strings as its response in a $http.post call? Right now, when I do a $http.post call, my response is in string but angularjs by default uses JSON therefore I get an error. Right now I have something along the lines of

```
function getResponseURL(response) {
 //this will convert the response to string
                return response;
}
$http.defaults.transformResponse = [];
$http.defaults.transformResponse.unshift(getResponseURL);
```

However if I use the code above, any $http.post calls after that call uses string. I want it to use the original default JSON format. How can I go about into just temporarily changing the response to string for this one call but the rest stay as JSON type as a response?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not only register that transform for ONLY that request?

[Angular js $http docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http)

> If you wish
>   override the request/response transformations only for a single
>   request then provide transformRequest and/or transformResponse
>   properties on the configuration object passed into $http.